If a language L over a finite alphabet A has both a subset and superset that are Turing-recognizable, does this make L Turing-Recognizable too?
"Let A be a finite alphabet, and let L1 and L2 be two Turing-recognisable languages over A such that L1 is a proper subset of L2, i.e. L1 ⊂ L2 but L1 ≠ L2. Let a language L over the alphabet A satisfy that L1 ⊂ L ⊂ L2. Does L have to be Turing-recognisable as well? Justify your answer." I am unsure about the answer to this question. My initial answer was yes, L has to be Turing-recognisable as well, because I couldn't find an example where it is not given that both L1 and L2 are, and L1 ⊂ L ⊂ L2.

Hint: consider the empty set and the set of all strings.

That kind of confuses me even more. I thought the empty set (ε) was not Turing-recognizable. Does A* (the set of all strings) contain ε as well?

@Theo You are misunderstanding a few concepts here.
$\varepsilon$ isn't the empty set, $\emptyset$ is.
And $\emptyset$ is recognisable by a TM that simply rejects everything.
$\varepsilon$ is the empty string, and is contained in $A^*$.
